# Why my composite key is not working in @ManyToOne?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want make shared primary key in Spring data jpa, everything is fine untill i`m using @ManyToOne
whats wrong?

my entities:

```
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private String name;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private IDCard idCard;

}

@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class IDCard {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Person person;

private Long inn;

@JsonIgnore
public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
}
}
```

result (if i`m using @OneToOne it works):

[@OneToOne result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASIt8.png)

when i`m switching @OneToMany there`s diffrent id:
[@ManyToOne result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrxLz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering only the mapping of the association, the fields should look something like:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    // This field is optional, it's useful only if you want a bidirectional association
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<IDCard> idCards;

}
```

```
@Entity
public class IDCard {

    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;
  

}
```

Please, check [many-to-one mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-one) in the Hibernate ORM guide for more details.